# Having trouble with Javascript ordering form not calculating

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm getting a null error with my order form when I'm trying to calculate the total using javascript.  I believe I have everything done.  I get an error on line 13 below that starts with .innerHTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doTotals() {

var strains = ['guptakush_', 'headbandguptakush_', 'purplejuicyfruitguptakush_', 'hibiscussunrise_', 'criticalkushguptakush_', 'columbiagoldguptakush_', 'grapeapeguptakush_', 'krishnakush_', 'durbinpoisonguptakush_', 'purpleeurkleguptakush_', 'columbiagoldafgani_', 'kandykushguptakush_', 'hibiscussunriseafgani_', 'afgani_', 'grapeapeafgani_', 'krishnaafgani_', 'hashplantafgani_', 'durbinpoisonafgani_'];
var priceStr = 'price';
var quantityStr = 'quantity';
var subtotalStr = 'subtotal';
var total = 0.00;
for (var i = 0; i < strains.length; i++) {
    var price = document.getElementById(strains[i] + priceStr).value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById(strains[i] + quantityStr).value;
    document.getElementById(strains[i] + subtotalStr)
        .innerHTML = parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
    total += price * quantity;
}
document.getElementById("finaltotal").innerHTML = total;
}

function setup() {
var lastCol = document.getElementById("subtotal_header");

var theForm = document.getElementById("orderform");

var amounts = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for(var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){
    amounts[i].onchange = doTotals;
}

}

window.onload = setup;

</script>
```

Here is the HTML that is associated just one example they are all the same with unique id and names.

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
<label class="form-control-label" for="guptakush_quantity">Gupta Kush</label>
<input type="hidden" id="guptakush_price" value="1.00">
<select class="form-control-inline form-control-sm" id="guptakush_quantity" name="guptakush_quantity" size="1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="guptakush_subtotal">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">$</div>
    </div>
<input type="text" class="form-control-inline col-sm-1" id="finaltotal" name="finaltotal" placeholder="$0.00" readonly>
</div>
```

Full Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/dg260zxf/

Also if I could just make this work without the subtotal since I don't think it's necessary that would be awesome.

Comment: But you don't tell us the error?

Comment: Sorry:  TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Your `<td>` is not correct. HTML is not valid. Why are you using a <td> at all outside a table?

Comment: Sorry I fixed that same error...

Comment: I suggest you go to codepen or jsfiddle and create an example that demonstrates your failing code.

Comment: changed it to an input hidden

Comment: You cannot set the `innerHTML` of an `<input>`. Just create an example, like I suggested.

Comment: fiddle example created and added to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the array contains many Divs than not in HTML,

the first item **'guptakush_'** only exist in html

so if you check if div exists before settings value it will resolve the problem 
+
the finaltotal is input not html so put new value with **.value** not **.inerHTML**

Working demo:

```js
function doTotals() {

  var strains = ['guptakush_', 'headbandguptakush_', 'purplejuicyfruitguptakush_', 'hibiscussunrise_', 'criticalkushguptakush_', 'columbiagoldguptakush_', 'grapeapeguptakush_', 'krishnakush_', 'durbinpoisonguptakush_', 'purpleeurkleguptakush_', 'columbiagoldafgani_', 'kandykushguptakush_', 'hibiscussunriseafgani_', 'afgani_', 'grapeapeafgani_', 'krishnaafgani_', 'hashplantafgani_', 'durbinpoisonafgani_'];
  
  var priceStr = 'price';
  var quantityStr = 'quantity';
  var subtotalStr = 'subtotal';
  var total = 0.00;
  for (var i = 0; i < strains.length; i++) {
    var priceInput = document.getElementById(strains[i] + priceStr);
    var quantityInput = document.getElementById(strains[i] + quantityStr);
    var subTotalDiv = document.getElementById(strains[i] + subtotalStr);

      if(subTotalDiv) {
        var price = priceInput.value;
        var quantity = quantityInput.value;

        subTotalDiv
          .innerHTML = parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
        total += price * quantity;
      }
  }

  document.getElementById("finaltotal").value = total;
}

function setup() {
  var lastCol = document.getElementById("subtotal_header");

  var theForm = document.getElementById("orderform");

  var amounts = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
  for(var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){
      amounts[i].onchange = doTotals;
  }

}

window.onload = setup;
```

```html
<div class="form-group mb-3">
<label class="form-control-label" for="guptakush_quantity">Gupta Kush</label>
<input type="hidden" id="guptakush_price" value="1.00">
<select class="form-control-inline form-control-sm" id="guptakush_quantity" name="guptakush_quantity" size="1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="guptakush_subtotal">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">$</div>
    </div>
<input type="text" class="form-control-inline col-sm-1" id="finaltotal" name="finaltotal" placeholder="$0.00" readonly>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of issues:

1. You hadn't defined `subtotalStr`, so that was null
2. You weren't executing your setup function because you didn't include parentheses
3. Your `<strong>` element doesn't seem to be populatable when selecting it by ID (not sure what was up w/that, but changing it to a div worked).

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/mj1z9bvq/

In my version, I fixed the first two problems.  And then for the first `<strong>` element, I replaced it with a `<div>` so you could see the output.  You'll have to go through and do something similar for the others.